# Get value of multiple select list values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im wanting to collect the selected value of a select list, and insert the value into span tag. I am using the msDropdown jquery plugin which skins the select list.

The code below initiates the plugin, but how i would alter it to so that it outputs the value of the selected option to a span tag each time user selects an option?

I know the answer is simple, and I do have some rough skills with jquery, but my brain has buckled because ive been coding in PHP for the past week and am finding it hard to remember how to tackle this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#websites2").msDropDown({mainCSS:'dd2'});


})
```

All help is appreciated, cheers Lea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the change listener to your select and then initialize the msDropDown. This works for me on the demo at http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown.

```
$('#websites2').change(function() {
    $('#id-span').html($('#websites2').val());
});
$("#websites2").msDropDown({mainCSS:'dd2'});
```